# Can a transitive class model be absolute for all formulas?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let me define an absoluteness of a formula for a class.
$\phi$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$  iff $$\forall x,y,z\in\mathbf{M}(\phi^{\mathbf{M}}(x,y,z)\leftrightarrow\phi(x,y,z))$$

If a class $\mathbf{M}\neq\mathbf{V}$ is a transitive model of $ZFC$, can we always find a formula $\phi(x,y,z,...)$ of set theory (or prove its existence) which is not absolute for $\mathbf{M}$?

Thank you for all your answers

Comment: Does "absolute for ${\bf M}$" mean "true in ${\bf M}$ iff true"? If so, consider ${\bf M}=V$. (If not, what does it mean?)

Comment: Yes, I've just edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you mean also $M\neq V$, this is impossible. Consider the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which states that $x=\mathcal P(y)$. If the formula is absolute, then for every ordinal $\alpha$ we get that $\mathcal P(\alpha)^M=\mathcal P(\alpha)$. Therefore the two models must have the same sets of ordinals, and by the Balcar–Vopěnka theorem they must be equal.

(The Balcar–Vopěnka theorem states that two models of $\sf ZF$ with the same sets of ordinals are equal, provided one of them also satisfies $\sf AC$.)

In lieu of choice we can iterate the power set construction which gives us the von Neumann hierarchy, as Elliot Glazer suggests in the comments, and we can take the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ to mean "$x$ is an ordinal and $y=V_x$", and directly prove that the von Neumann hierarchies are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I hope someone else will come along and prove that this is impossible, or that it is indeed a consequence of some very large cardinal axiom. You should wait with accepting my answer for a few days, I think.

Comment: If $M$ is an elementary submodel of $V,$ doesn't that give that function $\alpha \mapsto V_{\alpha}$ is absolute to $M,$ so $M=V?$ (of course I'm assuming $M$ has all the ordinals, this doesn't apply if we're willing to consider transitive sets $M$).

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: I don't see why *directly*, but you're right: $\varphi(x,y)$ stating $x=\mathcal P(y)$ is absolute, so both models have the same sets of ordinals.

Comment: Can't we just use $\varphi(x,\alpha)$ stating that $\alpha \in \text{Ord}$ and $x=V_{\alpha}?$

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: Yes. This is why I said that you're right, but to define $V_\alpha$, etc. you need to utilise power sets anyway.

Comment: Sorry but how do I prove that if $\gamma\in\mathbf{V}$ is a limit ordinal and $\forall \beta\lt\gamma(P(\beta)\in\mathbf{M})$, then $\gamma\in\mathbf{M}$ (where $\mathbf{M}$ is a transitive class model of $ZFC$)?

Comment: @drert: If it is a transitive class model, it must contain all the ordinals.

Comment: I don't really know why transitive class models of ZFC contain all ordinals. Can I get any answers? Is it because it jsut satisfies all axioms of ZFC?

Comment: @drert: Because if $M$ satisfies, amongst other axioms, Replacement, then every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal, so if $M$ is a proper class it must contain a proper class of ordinals. And if it is transitive, this class must be the class of ordinals. Asking about absoluteness and inner models before you understand basic things about models of ZFC means that you might be jumping too far ahead.

Comment: Really thank you for your advice.